# list permutations in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, permutation

So I'm new to haskell and I've been playing with it for a while now. I want to get my function that outputs all list permutations to work. I have written 2 implementations, one works well, the other is giving me an error. Any help would be awesome.

This is the first (working) implementation:

```
permute [] = [[]]
permute xs = [y| x <- xs, y <- map (x:) $ permute $ delete x xs]
```

This one is giving me an error:

```
permute [] = [[]]
permute xs = map (\x -> map (x:) $ permute $ delete x xs) xs
```

and here's the error message:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
Expected type: [t0]
Actual type: [[t0]]
In the expression: map (x :) $ permute $ delete x xs
In the first argument of `map', namely
`(\ x -> map (x :) $ permute $ delete x xs)'
```

I'd appreciate if someone could explain why I'm getting this error. Thanks

Comment: Note that this approach with `delete` is rather inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I am planning to check out the implementation in Data.List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use type signatures to make the compiler's life easier.

`permute :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`, and now we have:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for permute :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
      at perm.hs:4:1
Expected type: [a]
  Actual type: [[a]] 
In the expression: map (x :) $ permute $ xs
In the first argument of `map', namely
  `(\ x -> map (x :) $ permute $ xs)'
```

So, seems like we need to use `concatMap` instead of `map`.

```
permute :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
permute [] = [[]]
permute xs = concatMap (\x -> map (x:) $ permute $ delete x xs) xs
```

Comment: Thanks, that made perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you are not sure that you have a type `deriving Eq` (reqiured to use `delete`):

```
perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms [a] = [[a]]
perms [a,b] = [[a,b],[b,a]]
perms xs = concatMap f [0..length xs - 1] where
  f i = map ((xs!!i):) $ perms $ exclude i xs
  exclude n xs = take (n) xs ++ drop (n+1) xs
```

Maybe it is an overkill :)